# WIX/MSI setup writes to HKLM despite MSIINSTALLPERUSER=1

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I try to create a [MSI Single Package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd408068(v=vs.85).aspx) using WIX (3.10). The user can select in the UI whether the package should install Per-User or Per-Machine. The package is initialized with `ALLUSERS=2` and `MSIINSTALLPERUSER=1`. I did not set an `InstallScope`, as this would limit the Package to one or the other.

If the user selects Per-Machine the setup continues with `ALLUSERS=2` and `MSIINSTALLPERUSER=""`. - Everything works as expected.

If the user chooses Per-User installation `ALLUSERS=2` and `MSIINSTALLPERUSER=1` remain unchanged. If a **non-privileged** user runs the setup everything works as expected as well.

But if a **privileged** user executes the setup and chooses **Per-User** installation, registry keys that should be written to `HKCU\Software\Classes\` are still written to `HKCR` / `HKLM\Software\Classes\`. This happens without UAC being invoked. 
I observed this behavior on a Windows 8.1 (current patch level).

This is not what I want. If the user selects Per-User installation, there should be nothing written to HKLM/HKCR.

Here is sample from the wxs-file:

```
<Component Id="MyRegistryComponent" Guid="{99999999-9999-9999-9999-999999999999}">
    <RegistryValue Id="MyRegistryComponent_MainKey" Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Classes\myapp.myclass" Value="myapp.myclass.foo" Type="string" />
</Component>
```

I checked the MSI with Orca. This `RegistryValue` has Root=1 in the Registry table of the MSI.

I tried/checked already:

- I verified that the `ALLUSERS` and `MSIINSTALLPERUSER` properties are
  indeed set as stated above.
- I tried setting `ALLUSERS=""` `MSIINSTALLPERUSER=1` – No effect.
- I changed `Root="HKCU"` to `Root="HKMU"` in the wxs.
  This results in Root=-1 in the MSI, but I does not change the final
  result after installation.

What am I missing here?
Is possible that this behavior is caused by previous incomplete (un-)installations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "This results in Root=-1 in the MSI, but I does not change the final result after installation." it's not clear which of the results you're referring to but:

1. HKCU will always go to HKCU, HKMU is what you need to switch between HKCU and HKLM in a single package setup. So using HKMU and producing a verbose log would be useful to see if there is a failure somewhere in there.
2. You will get changes in HKCR. That's usually the normal behavior because as this article explains:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724475(v=vs.85).aspx

Quote "The HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes key contains default settings that can apply to all users on the local computer. The HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes key contains settings that apply only to the interactive user. The HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT key provides a view of the registry that merges the information from these two sources. HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT also provides this merged view for applications designed for previous versions of Windows."

HKCR is a virtual view that combines class registration for the current user with class registration for the machine to present a view of all class entries on the system. Other accounts (such as the system account) will see only HKLM, so what you see exactly depends on who you are.

I suggest that is what is needed here is a test case that uses HKMU as is required, and maybe post that test case. Keep in mind that seeing HKCR entries is normal, going by the documentation, so maybe that explains all that you are seeing.

Comment: Thank you! Lots of valuable hints and info. This probably is the answer. - Will check tomorrow. - Feel like downvoting my own question now. :-/

Comment: Is there any kind of official documentation for "HKMU"? When I try to google it, I only find tons of answers on stackoverflow.com. Neither Microsoft nor WiX mention "HKMU" anywhere.